# Why can't clojure.repl/print-doc binding be changed in Clojure REPL?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

This works as expected:

```
java -jar clojure-1.4.0.jar -e "(do (require 'clojure.repl) (.setDynamic #'clojure.repl/print-doc) (with-bindings {#'clojure.repl/print-doc str} (eval '(clojure.repl/doc println))))"
```

Output:

```
"{:ns #<Namespace clojure.core>, :name println, :arglists ([& more]), :added \"1.0\", :static true, :doc \"Same as print followed by (newline)\", :line 3325, :file \"clojure/core.clj\"}"
```

But the same does not work in the REPL:

```
java -jar clojure-1.4.0.jar -e "(do (require 'clojure.repl) (.setDynamic #'clojure.repl/print-doc) (clojure.main/repl :init (fn [] {#'clojure.repl/print-doc str}))))"
```

Output of `(doc println)`:

```
user=> (doc println)
-------------------------
clojure.core/println
([& more])
  Same as print followed by (newline)
nil
user=>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @noahz İ'm expecting the map output above. İ don't understand why the binding works outside of the REPL but not inside the REPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer after diving into the counterclockwise and nrepl code:

```
java -jar clojure-1.4.0.jar -e "(do (require 'clojure.repl) (.setDynamic #'clojure.repl/print-doc) (with-bindings {#'clojure.repl/print-doc str} (clojure.main/repl)))))"
```

The output is the same as above:

```
"{:ns #<Namespace clojure.core>, :name println, :arglists ([& more]), :added \"1.0\", :static true, :doc \"Same as print followed by (newline)\", :line 3325, :file \"clojure/core.clj\"}"
```

The trick is to use `with-bindings` before calling `repl`:

```
(with-bindings {#'clojure.repl/print-doc str}
  (repl))
```